# Amchart text wrap

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Hi how can I make the text circular on first index children of amchart pie and then radial on the others?

```
// Create series
var series = container.children.push(am5hierarchy.Sunburst.new(root, {
  singleBranchOnly: true,
  downDepth: 2,
  initialDepth: 4,
  topDepth: 1,
  innerRadius: 100,
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "name",
  childDataField: "children"
}));

series.nodes.template.setAll({
  tooltipText: "{category}"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStrc.png)
});

series.slices.template.setAll({
  templateField: "nodeSettings"
});

series.labels.template.setAll({
  fontSize: 12,
  text: "{category}",
  inside: true,
  radius: 10,
  textType:"circular",//circular
  fill: am5.color(0xffffff)
})
```

i want the text to be radial on the 3rd index and 2nd maybe.

I need to make the text radial instead of circular in some conditions

Comment: series.labels.template.setAll({
  fontSize: 12,
  text: "{category}",
  inside: true,
  radius: 10,
  textType:"circular",//circular
  fill: am5.color(0xffffff)
})

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.